# How to launch the application after a quiet call to Wix burn bootstrap

Tags: wix, burn

I have a Wix burn project. When UI is shown, the user can push the launch button and start the application after the install.

I use `<Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[InstallFolder]\executable_name.exe"/>`

The problem is I also use the same project for silent upgrades, calling the executable in quiet mode. How can I also auto start the application in that situation?

Thank you.